# How do I render multiple contexts to the same HTML in Django

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

This is just a question to know about Django. I have two views and I am rendering two contexts to two views.How can I render both the contexts to the same HTML template?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, you could just call the same template file in your two views functions when rendering:

```
def your_view_1(request):
    context_1: dict = {'key': 'a_string_depending_on_request_or_view'}
    return render(request, 'common_template.html', context_1)

def your_view_2(request):
    context_2: dict = {'key': 'another_string'}
    return render(request, 'common_template.html', context_2)
```

Comment: and how do I add them in urls.py?

Comment: and how do I add them in urls.py?Actually I get a problem that I could access only one of the variable in jinja template.One of them doesnt show up any value @bolino

Comment: Just put two "path" or "re_path" in your urls.py, calling each of your views. About the template, it doesn't need to use all the variables in the context, so you can use only part of them if you want to.

Comment: Could you specify an example of above mentioned comment? @bolino

Comment: e.g.  `urlpatterns = [path('path-1/', views.your_view_1, name='view-name-1'), path('path-2/', views.your_view_2, name='view-name-2'),]`

Comment: but I want the values to be retained on same url path.I laready tried the above one but it is not what I want. I actually need both the contexts on single url path and both of the values needs to be retained. @bolino

Comment: ,or atleast I want the values in path-1 to be carried to path-2.Is that possible?

Comment: In that case use only one path with parameters, and one view with different logic in the view depending on the parameters.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
def view_1(request):
    context_1: dict = {
     //Your key/value pairs
     check = False
    }
    return render(request, 'common_template.html', context_1)

def view_2(request):
    context_2: dict = {
    //Your other key value pairs
    check = True
    }
    return render(request, 'common_template.html', context_2)
```

And then in your template, you can do an if-else

```
{% if check %}
//do stuff related to view2
{% else %}
//do stuff related to view1 %}
{%endif%}
```

Comment: but I already have a dictionary coming from another class which doesn't have any flags like check

Comment: but I already have a dictionary coming from another class which doesn't have any flags like check

Comment: In that case, you can use bolino's answer if the keys are same, and values are different. However, if keys are also different check whether they are null, and if not then do stuff.

Comment: no my keys are different.Why do I have to use a condition.Can't I directly reference the variable in the HTML file? @Abhishek

Comment: @Sri Test Yes you can directly refer them but for someone else reading the code in your template, it won't make much sense as to what thing is coming from which view. Although I am not understanding what exactly you want to ask here?